# Seleccionar id de usuario e insertar en otra tabla

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Tengo un problema que no consigo resolver.

Ejem: tabla 1 y tabla 2, en tabla 1 ya tengo registrado el user y este ya está con la session iniciada con id1. En la tabla 2 estoy intentado insertar el id1
y otros datos de otro form.

Para explicarme mejor estoy intentado seleccionar una clave primaria e insertar esta en otra tabla como clave extranjera, siendo que el user ya está con session iniciada.

Ya busque información en el manual de php pero no consigo hacer que el `INSERT_ID()` O EL `LAST_INSERT_ID` funcione siempre me presenta algún error.

```
<?php
session_start();
require'funcs/conexion.php';


$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$numero =$_POST['numero'];
$nomebanco = $_POST['nomebanco'];
$agencia =$_POST['agencia'];
$conta=$_POST['conta'];

$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
$selecionaid = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id='$idUsuario'";
$result = $mysqli->query($selecionaid);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbbancarios (cpf, numero, nomebanco, agencia, conta) VALUES ('#cpf', '$numero', '$nomebanco', '$agencia', '$conta', '$result')";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($resultado) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

En la pregunta se ven varios fallos de sintaxis, aunque alguna puede ser a la hora de formular esta.

Cuando haces el `INSERT INTO tbbancarios`, especificas 5 campos (`(cpf, numero, nomebanco, agencia, conta)`) pero luego le pasas 6 valores (`'#cpf', '$numero', '$nomebanco', '$agencia', '$conta', '$result')`). Además `#cpf` está mal escrito ya que debería ser `$cpf` y si el campo es de tipo numérico este debería ir sin comillas.

Por otro lado en el `$result` del primer select coges todos los datos del usuario (que no especificas cuales son) y los metes todos en la segunda consulta.

Si quieres obtener sólo la id para meterla en la segunda tabla porque haces un `SELECT *`?

Y si es eso lo que quieres, el select no te devuelve la misma id que tiene tu variable `$idUsuario`?

En este caso necesitas hacer esto:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbbancarios (cpf, numero, nomebanco, agencia, conta, idusuario) VALUES ('$cpf', '$numero', '$nomebanco', '$agencia', '$conta', '$idUsuario')";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Comment: Entendido, lo he cambiado pero sigo teniendo dudas referente a como hago para insertar el id de user en la tabla 2.

Comment: $selecionaid = "SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE id='$idUsuario'";
$result = $mysqli->query($selecionaid);
 
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbbancarios (cpf, numero, nomebanco, agencia, conta, idusuario) VALUES ($cpf, $numero, '$nomebanco', $agencia, $conta, $result)";

Comment: No necesitas hacer un select ya que tienes la id en $idusuario.

Comment: Conseguiiiiiii, muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya me estaba volviendo loco com esto y era algo tan simples.

Comment: me alegro de haber ayudado